# $('*').not('input') doesn't work for password fields in chrome?

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am selecting all tags that are not input tags to bind a hotkey to.

```
$('*').not('input').bindHotKey(blah);
```

However, this doesn't seem to exclude the password field in chrome. ie: `<input type="password"/>`

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/HT5sS/ Or am I missing something?

Comment: That's it, @Felix Kling you should put this as an answer. It's the `body *` selector that does the job.

Comment: @Felix Kling, you have inadvertently solved my problem. The issue is that I used $('*') instead of $('body *') so my selector is probably selecting some random thing behind the password field. Thanks! Post this as your answer so I can vote it up.

Comment: This is what happens if you comment on answers early in the morning :D I should do this more often...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to only select the descendants of the `body` element:

```
$('body *').not('input').bindHotKey(blah);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/HT5sS/)

**Update:**
But it even seems to work with `$('*')`. Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/HT5sS/1/). Without `not` there are 11 elements in the page, with `not`, 10.

Comment: That's weird, I just put the code in and a VERY strange behavior is occuring, now NOTHING is triggering the hotkey EXCEPT the password field. hmm

Comment: @Razor Storm: Mmh. Could you create a jsfiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I cant seem to reproduce the problem, but I'll set up my server and link the website in a bit.